# why does this code generates an eror when setting a frame to invisible?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

i'm trying to hide the current frame, when the user clicks the button
but it generates an error

i have tried to create a method and call it in the actionlistener but it still not ok

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        AddBook add1=new AddBook();
        add1.show();
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }});
btnAdd.setBounds(135, 113, 101, 49);
contentPane.add(btnAdd);
```

frame cannot be resolved

Comment: `btnAdd.setBounds(135, 113, 101, 49);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `frame` variable is not accessible in the scope your `ActionListener` is being defined.

Either:

- Make `frame` accessible using a field or simply defining the `ActionListener` after the `frame` (eg: `JFrame frame = new JFrame(..); btn.addActionListener(...);`), but before the `setVisible(true)`.
- Try to find the `Window` in which the button is, [SwingUtilities::windowForComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent(java.awt.Component)) may help, or if you want the focused window, combine [KeyboardFocusManager::getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()), [KeyboardFocusManager::getFocusOwner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getFocusOwner()) and [SwingUtilities::windowForComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent(java.awt.Component)).